# Obtain sub-cv::Mat from a given image such that

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I have a processed an image that returns a Mat say:

```
[
[ 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

are there any segmentation functions that can help me isolate individually ?
if not so what would be the best approach ?

i.e. say if i do mysegment(Mat a,0) should return

```
[
[ 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

then mysegment(Mat a,1) will return

```
[
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I consider continuous 255 pixels to be a block. Now I want to iterate over or process these blocks ... since more than one block can be formed in a matrix.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what your question is. What are you trying to "isolate individually"?

Comment: @Aurelius i have a set of blocks ... i consider continuous '255' pixels to be a block ... there can be n such blocks ... i want to isolate them

Comment: hey guys got it ... you can use contours ... :D :D

Comment: find contours -> draw contours works indeed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use contours

```
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

the link to the [library](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)